# Sum grades only if they have been entered

Tags: google-sheets, logic, google-sheets-formula

Trying to make a progressive grade calculator using Google Sheets.

```
--------Type --- Earned --- Possible

- Quizzes------ 97 --- 100
- Exam 1------- 92 --- 100
- Exam 2-------___ --- 100
- Exam 3-------___ --- 100
- Final Exam---___ --- 100

[ Total -------------- 189 ---- 200 ]
```

I was trying to use a `sumif` function but I can't figure out how to check for not-blank spaces.

This does not work:

```
 =SUMIF(G2:G6,not(isblank(G2:G6)),H2:H6)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use

```
     =SUMIF(G2:G6,">0",H2:H6)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked perfectly